# Send Thermal Image with mlx90640 via TCP

Tags: python, opencv, tcp, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a problem with my program I am trying to send the images I collect from the MLX90640 thanks to the Raspberry to process them in a remote PC.
I am using a Raspberry 4 as a client and the data is routed to a PC. I am using the socket to start the server which is to receive and the images and thermal images. For the images connected to the camera, I took care of it my problem is to transfer the thermal images. I am currently using a wifi connection that I share with my cellphone for the tests.If necessary I will post the server code.  But I have this error message I have tried many solutions and I have not found it. In fact, the Raspberry is the client and the PC is the server. So I collect data from the raspberry to transmit it to the PC for processing. I want to detect the temperature of the face and for that the MLX90640 which is connected to the Raspberry must send the thermal data. Knowing that it collects 768 values, so I want these values ​​to be transmitted or the maximum value to be returned to the PC. Can someone help me

````
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import pickle
import zlib
import adafruit_mlx90640
import board
import busio
import numpy as np

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('192.168.43.134', 8485))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=800000)
mlx = adafruit_mlx90640.MLX90640(i2c)
print("MLX addr detected on I2C")
print([hex(i) for i in mlx.serial_number])
mlx.refresh_rate = adafruit_mlx90640.RefreshRate.REFRESH_4_HZ
frame1 = np.zeros((24*32,))
#max_t=0
#moy = 0
#cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#mlx.set(3, 32);
#mlx.set(4, 24);

img_counter = 0

encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]

while True:
    frame = mlx.getFrame(frame1)
    result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
#    data = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(frame, 0))
    data = pickle.dumps(frame, 0)
    size = len(data)

    print("{}: {}".format(img_counter, size))
    client_socket.sendall(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
    img_counter += 1

```Traceback (most recent call last): File "client1.py", line 37, in <module> result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /home/pi/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp:145: error: (-10:Unknown error code -10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function 'throwOnEror'
````

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client1.py", line 37, in <module>
    result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /home/pi/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp:145: error: (-10:Unknown error code -10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function 'throwOnEror'

Comment: it is the error

Comment: Your setup is quite unclear. What computer is your code running on? How is it connected to a Raspberry Pi? Wired? Wireless? Where's the code for the receiving end? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Why are you chatting with yourself in the comments. Please click `edit` and make sure your question is complete and up-to-date. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you manage to get thermal at Raspberry pi? I did a similar approach but i am not using thermal camera. If your problem is not able to transfer image from raspberry pi to your computer

Server code at Raspberry pi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import socket
import select
import queue
import pickle
import struct
import time
from threading import Thread

class WebcamVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
        self.stream .set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,1)
        self.stream .set(5, 60)
        self.stream .set(3,640)
        self.stream .set(4,480)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
        return self
    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.stopped:
                return
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
            time.sleep(0.1)
    def read(self):
        img= cv2.cvtColor(self.frame , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        data = pickle.dumps(img)
        return data
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True


def commandParser(cmd, stream):
    reply = ""
    if(cmd == "getimage"):
        reply = stream.read()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        reply = '/n'.encode()
    return(reply)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    camera_idx = 0
    for i in range(3):
        stream = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
        test,frame = stream.read()
        stream.release()
        if test == True:
            camera_idx = i
            break
    #stream = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_idx)
    vs = WebcamVideoStream(src=camera_idx).start()

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    port = 8080
    server.bind(('192.168.128.14', port))
    server.listen(5)
    inputs = [server]
    outputs = []
    message_queues = {}
    cmd =""
    while inputs:
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, 1)
        for s in readable:
            if s is server:
                connection, client_address = s.accept()
                inputs.append(connection)
                message_queues[connection] = queue.Queue(1024)
            else:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    cmd = data.decode()
                    message_queues[s].put(commandParser(data.decode(), vs))
                    if s not in outputs:
                                    outputs.append(s)
                else:
                    if s in outputs:
                        outputs.remove(s)
                    inputs.remove(s)
                    s.close()
                    del message_queues[s]

        for s in writable:
            try:
                next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                outputs.remove(s)

            else:
                if(cmd == "getimage"):
                    size = len(next_msg)
                    s.sendall(struct.pack(">L", size) + next_msg)
                else:
                    s.send("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNONOOO".encode())


        for s in exceptional:
            print ('handling exceptional condition for', s.getpeername())
            inputs.remove(s)
            if s in outputs:
                outputs.remove(s)
            s.close()
            del message_queues[s]
    vs.stop()
```

Client Code at PC

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct ## new
import zlib
import time

server_address = ('192.168.128.14', 8080)



s =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#print ('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
s.connect(server_address)

cv2.namedWindow('Streaming')
payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")

while True:
    s.send("getimage".encode())

    data = b""
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += s.recv(4096)

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += s.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]
    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
    cv2.imshow('Streaming',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    #cv2.imwrite("test.tiff", frame)
s.close()
```

Comment: Well, transferring images from the webcam is not a problem. In fact, the Raspberry is the client and the PC is the server. So I collect data from the raspberry to transmit it to the PC for processing. I want to detect the temperature of the face and for that the MLX90640 which is connected to the Raspberry must send the thermal data. Knowing that it collects 768 values, so I want these values ​​to be transmitted or the maximum value to be returned to the PC

Comment: you can get the temperature value using separate command. You are using adafruit library you can refer to https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MLX90640/blob/master/examples/mlx90640_simpletest.py to get the temperature value.